# I want to know how many groups of 2 and 3 I am going to end up with from 2 different lists.

Tags: linear-algebra, divisibility

I am presented with two lists of students. One list is from school A and another from school B.
I have to form groups that can contain either 3 students or 2 but they have to be from different schools. (in a group of 3: 2 students are from school A and 1 student is from school B) (in a group of 2 one is from school A and one is from school B).

Is there a way where i can know how many groups of 3 and how many groups of 2 i have to form before doing any matching? We can also add in as many groups as we need to meet the criteria.

EX: list from school A have 100 students and list from school B have 150 students. To form groups that meet the criteria listed above i have:
50 groups of 3 (2 students from B and 1 student from A)
50 groups of 2 (1 student from B and 1 student from A)

Comment: Try defining some variables and writing some equations.  Welcome to MSE.

Comment: check my edit! and thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see that you've made significant progress.  What are the variables (unknowns)?  Where are the equations?  I'll get you started.  Let the number of students from schools A and B be $a$ and $b$, respectively.  So in your example, $a=100,\ b=150$.  We want to known how many groups of $3$ and how many groups of two we need, so these are the unknowns.  Let $x$ be the number of groups of $3$ and let $y$ be the number of groups of $2$.  Now we need some equations relating $a,b,x,$ and $y$.  Over to you.

Comment: Sorry but "I am gonna end up" is not standard english.